# The :python command doesn't work - E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version

Tags: vimscript-python, compile-vim

I am trying to use Python in `vim`, but it doesn't work despite `vim` having the `+python3` option.

```
:python print("hello")
```

gives

```
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version
```

**Question:** How can this problem be fixed?

The `:version` command's output:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 06 2019 17:31:41)
Included patches: 1-1453
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -dnd               +listcmds          +postscript        +timers
+arabic            -ebcdic            +localmap          +printer           +title
+autocmd           +emacs_tags        -lua               +profile           -toolbar
-autoservername    +eval              +menu              -python            +user_commands
-balloon_eval      +ex_extra          +mksession         +python3           +vertsplit
+balloon_eval_term +extra_search      +modify_fname      +quickfix          +virtualedit
-browse            +farsi             +mouse             +reltime           +visual
++builtin_terms    +file_in_path      -mouseshape        +rightleft         +visualextra
+byte_offset       +find_in_path      +mouse_dec         -ruby              +viminfo
+channel           +float             +mouse_gpm         +scrollbind        +vreplace
+cindent           +folding           -mouse_jsbterm     +signs             +wildignore
-clientserver      -footer            +mouse_netterm     +smartindent       +wildmenu
-clipboard         +fork()            +mouse_sgr         +startuptime       +windows
+cmdline_compl     +gettext           -mouse_sysmouse    +statusline        +writebackup
+cmdline_hist      -hangul_input      +mouse_urxvt       -sun_workshop      -X11
+cmdline_info      +iconv             +mouse_xterm       +syntax            -xfontset
+comments          +insert_expand     +multi_byte        +tag_binary        -xim
+conceal           +job               +multi_lang        +tag_old_static    -xpm
+cryptv            +jumplist          -mzscheme          -tag_any_white     -xsmp
+cscope            +keymap            +netbeans_intg     -tcl               -xterm_clipboard
+cursorbind        +lambda            +num64             +termguicolors     -xterm_save
+cursorshape       +langmap           +packages          +terminal
+dialog_con        +libcall           +path_extra        +terminfo
+diff              +linebreak         -perl              +termresponse
+digraphs          +lispindent        +persistent_undo   +textobjects
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved.

The `:python3` or `:pythonx` (`:py3` or `:pyx`) should be used instead of the simple `:python`.

See `:h python3` and `:h pythonx`.

So, `:py3 print("hello")` gives `hello` as expected.

---

Also, to see what version of Python is being used, do:

```
:pyx import sys
:pyx print(sys.version)
```

in my case it gives

```
3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)
[GCC 8.3.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `:help if-pyth`: you need to use `:python3`.

Comment: `:h if-python` gives `E149: Sorry, no help for if-python`. Also, `:helpgrep if-python` gives `E480: No match: if-python`.

Comment: @MiniMax see edits